# Iframe ChatterPage

Tags: chatter, community, iframe

I have chatter page in iframe src but the new group button is not working.Anyone has same issue.

[image]

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false"
       docType="html-5.0">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <c:head />
  </head>
<body>
    <c:menu />
 <apex:iframe id="iframe" src="/community/_ui/core/chatter/ui/ChatterPage?isdtp=vw" 
                        scrolling="true" width="100%" height="500px"/> 
   </body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Tye making standard stylesheet=true and sidebar=true and showheader=true to see it works .Most of chatter functionality need EXTJS loaded and can be possible with sidebar and showheader

Comment: Thanks @MohithKumar.But I don't want the header and sidebar as I have custom header for my community

Comment: I really dont think there will be any solution unless you inspect and load chatter JS libraries yourself but thats not clean way to do this

Comment: I noticed when I iframed some Salesforce pages in a test Community that a lot of the javascript functionality to leave that page got disabled. Have you thought about moving your header into the HTML header for the community so you don't have to iframe?

Comment: our community is developed using force.com(visual force pages) with header(tabs)(visualforce component) containing links to each visual force page.